# gamm models in R

Tags: r, regression, mixed-models, gam, mgcv

I am trying to adapt my model to `gamm` (which I was using in `lmer`).

My former formula was

`b <- lmer(metric1~a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+(1|X) + (1|Y), data = dataset)`

I am trying to adapt this formula to modelling with `gamm`. But I could not figure out how yet. My purpose is to find the simplified model.

Any ideas or examples would me much appreciated.

Comment: It was an advise from an stackoverflow user. And yes he offered me `mgcv::gam`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you are fitting a linear mixed model with two i.i.d. random effects (on intercept).

There is no need to use `gamm` in this case. Using `gam` with `method = REML` will do.

```
gam(metric1~a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+ s(X, bs = 're') + s(Y, bs = 're'), data = dataset, method = 'REML')
```

Note I have not extended other fixed effects into smooth functions, which you may do it yourself.

If you have a large dataset, it is suggested to use `bam`, and note it is `method = 'fREML` in this case.

The difference between `gam` and `bam` in REML estimation, is that the former uses "outer" iteration, while the latter uses "performance" iteration. But for Gaussian data there's no difference, though `bam` itself is designed for large dataset, using iterative QR reduction and parallel computing on request.

Personally I think `gamm` is outdated. It does REML estimation using `lme` and `MASS::glmmPQL`, which is much less efficient then the penalized least squares adopted by `gam` and `bam`.

Comment: Perhaps one thing in gamm's favour is that you can get the RE variance components

Comment: THank you very much, I will try that. And indeed I am in the search for a model not "outdated". Thx!

Comment: @user20650 Indeed I just need R2 values of the model and the significance of each variable that take place in the final model.

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi    I have some questions. 1) I have 2 random effects (in that example X and Y). Code needs to be adapted for random effects? 2) Can I use nested random effects in gam? 3) Should I use raw data or Log transformed data? (I allready transformed my data) 4)One of my variables is 1/0 data. Can I use such variables in gam?